I want to cleanup up the DATA_PUMP_DIR on an RDS Oracle instance
I am porting an on-prim oracle database to AWS RDS Oracle.  I am using the datapump method which involves downloading the dump file from S3 to the DATA_PUMP_DIR on the RDS oracle instance.  I have all this working and I want to perform the same process again to refine and document, but when I try to download to the DATA_PUMP_DIR again the new dump file will not overwrite the old.  I need a way to either overwrite or better yet, delete files from the DATA_PUMP_DIR.  Any help would be appreciated.
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(rdsadmin.rds_file_util.listdir('DATA_PUMP_DIR')) ORDER BY MTIME;

returns a list of files and my file exists in that list by when I execute:


SQL> EXEC UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('DATA_PUMP_DIR','frts-dev.dmp');

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29283: invalid file operation: nonexistent file or path [29434]
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 251
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 1230
ORA-06512: at line 1


So yes, I had the file name wrong. so from sqlplus:
SQL>  EXEC UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('DATA_PUMP_DIR','frts_dev.dmp');
works.  Crazy how an extra set of eyes always helps.  thanks guys.

To remove a file you can use the utl_file package; which you might be trying to do in your rdbmsadmin.utl_file.fremove(), but that doesn't seem to exist so I think you've confused two things.
However, fremove is a procedure, not a function, so you would need to execute it in a PL/SQL context - as an anonymous block - not as part of a query:
begin
    utl_file.fremove('DATA_PUMP_DIR', 'file-dev.dmp');
end;
/

If you're using SQL*Plus or SQLcl or SQL Developer (and maybe other clients) you could also use the shorthand for an anonymous block:
exec utl_file.fremove('DATA_PUMP_DIR', 'file-dev.dmp');

which expands to the same thing in the background.

There is a knowledge base article which refers to doing this:

Check the space allocation for the data pump directory

If the allocated space of the data pump directory is more than expected, then find the .dmp files that can be removed:

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DATA_PUMP_DIR')) ORDER by mtime;


If this query finds .dmp files, then delete them with the following query. Replace the file name with the name of the .dmp files:

SQL> EXEC utl_file.fremove('DATA_PUMP_DIR','[file name]');


and in the documentation.

SELECT * FROM TABLE(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DATA_PUMP_DIR')) ORDER by mtime; returns a list of files within the DATA_PUMP_DIR and the file that I want to delete is listed; but when I execute EXEC utl_file.fremove('DATA_PUMP_DIR','[file name]'); I get the following:    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29283: invalid file operation: nonexistent file or path [29434]
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 251
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 1230
ORA-06512: at line 1

You changed [file name] in that to your actual file name, like 'file_dev.dmp', right?

@Steiner - "non-existent file or path"  suggests the name doesn't quite match, but as we can't see what listdir returns we can't verify that for you (and you changed the file name earlier, which is confusing). Also, stating the obvious even more, if you exec twice then the second one will fail because the file has gone...  I came across this discussion about problems doing this but that's about compressed files. I guess speak to support?

and now I see the "-" instead of "_"
